# Python/Pandas: Complicated Excel SUMIFS across dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I'm working with two dataframes, One called Sales, pictured here
[image]

And another dataframe, called Claims, which is pictured here
[image]

I would like to create a new column called "SUMIFS" in another dataframe entitled "Subset" (i.e. Subset['SUMIFS'] = ...), and I am wondering if it is possible to perform an excel like SUMIFS  operation across dataframes in pandas. The criteria for the SUMIFS would be:

**sumrange --** Sales['Vehicle Count']

**Criteria 1 --** Sales['Vehicle Production Month/Year'] = Claims['Vehicle Production Month/Year']

**Criteria 2 --** Sales['DIS since RUN DATE'] < Claims['Claim DIS']

Here is the Sales Dataframe in spreadsheet form

[image]

Here is the Claims Dataframe in spreadsheet form

[image]

And, Finally, here is the original formula that I'm using in excel, that I would like to convert to Python: =SUMIFS(Sales!$D$2:$D$1156, Sales!$A$2:$A$1156, Claims!B2, Sales!$E$2:$E$1156, <"&Claims!O2)

Comment: Hey Aseem, you probably want to `merge` those two dataframes, based on the key that joins them. After that you can use `.loc` to filter your dataframe based on said condition. After that you can select the `Vehicle Count` column and apply `.sum()` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the two data frames in Python already then you can just simply do this. Note: This will only work if both dataframes are sorted. (If you have an ID column sort this before running the following code)

```
Sales['Vehicle Count'][
(Sales['Vehicle Production Month/Year'] == Claims['Vehicle Production Month/Year'])
& ['DIS since RUN DATE'] < Claims['Claim DIS'])
].sum()
```

I am essentially filter the data by the two if conditions, so what's left is the ones you want. All you have to do is to sum it up. (This is a direct compare, whole series by another series)

Comment: not mine, but you might look into this; [mcve], [ask]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just started answering questions not too ago